# Command /Xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 252

Tags: xcode, ios

I am trying to build ASI HTTP REQUEST iPHONE, and it works fine on the simulator. When I build to my iPhone 4 or iPod touch 2G, I get all this:
[image]

Although sometimes I get exit code 252...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did u solve this issue then pls help me.thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the picture, it says "ld: unknown option: -demangle". Check your build options and disable things that have to do with demangling.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had this issue when writing a wrapper for Android NDK and iOS. I had a class like MyClass.h then MyClass.mm (iOS side) and MyClass.cpp. I was supposed to only include the .mm and not the .cpp.